# I want to write a script that can generate random addresses

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a script that can generate random addresses.
for example:

```
(34578 Dolphin Street, Wonka NY, 44506).
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
var address 

var streetNumber = ['25489', '87459', '35478', '15975', '95125', '78965']

var streetName = ['A street', 'B street', 'C street', 'D street', 'E street', 'F street',]

var cityName = ['Riyadh', 'Dammam', 'Jedda', 'Tabouk', 'Makka', 'Maddena', 'Haiel']

var stateName = ['Qassem State', 'North State', 'East State', 'South State', 'West State']

var zipCode = ['28889', '96459', '35748', '15005', '99625', '71465']
```

so what should I do now?

Comment: If you find an answer useful you can accept by clicking on the green check next to it, and/or you can upvote/downvote it by clicking on the arrows above the check.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking advantage of the `map` and `join` functions of the `Array`. All you need before you map the array is creating a function that accepts an array and returns a random element of the array, that can easily be done by selecting a random index between 0 and the size of the array - 1.

```
function getRandomElement(array) {
    // Math.random() does not include 1, so this range is from 0 to size - 1 
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
```

Now to create a random address you just need to add all the arrays inside another array and `map` those using the random function above. This will return an array of random address elements, on which you can use the `join` function to join all parts of the array into a string.

```
var template = [streetNumber, streetName, cityName, stateName, zipCode];

function getRandomAddress() {
    return template.map(getRandomElement).join(" ");
}
```

You can also add the text you want between the address elements, just make sure that you return as is in the `getRandomAddress` function. Please view the example below:

```js
var streetNumber = ["25489", "87459", "35478", "15975", "95125", "78965"];
var streetName = ["A street", "B street", "C street", "D street", "E street", "F street"];
var cityName = ["Riyadh", "Dammam", "Jedda", "Tabouk", "Makka", "Maddena", "Haiel"];
var stateName = ["Qassem State", "North State", "East State", "South State", "West State"];
var zipCode = ["28889", "96459", "35748", "15005", "99625", "71465"];

var template = [streetNumber, " ", streetName, ", ", cityName, " ", stateName, ", ", zipCode];

function getRandomAddress() {
  return template.map(getRandomElement).join("");
}

function getRandomElement(array) {
  if (array instanceof Array) return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  else return array;
}

document.querySelector("#refresh").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("#output").textContent = getRandomAddress();
});
```

```html
<button id="refresh">Get Random Address</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Some Helpful Links:

- [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to iterate over your data and add one of each array

```js
var streetNumber = ['25489', '87459', '35478', '15975', '95125', '78965']

var streetName = ['A street', 'B street', 'C street', 'D street', 'E street', 'F street',]

var cityName = ['Riyadh', 'Dammam', 'Jedda', 'Tabouk', 'Makka', 'Maddena', 'Haiel']

var stateName = ['Qassem State', 'North State', 'East State', 'South State', 'West State']

var zipCode = ['28889', '96459', '35748', '15005', '99625', '71465']

function getRandom(input) {
    return input[Math.floor((Math.random() * input.length))];
}

function createAdress() {
    return `${getRandom(streetNumber)} ${getRandom(streetName)} ${getRandom(cityName)} ${getRandom(stateName)} ${getRandom(zipCode)}`;
}

var address = createAdress();
console.log(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try generating random numbers: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;`

Min should be 0 and max should be `array.lenght`

Then you can do something like: `address = streetNumber[myRandNumber(streetNumber)]`

And in myRandNumber function calculate max based on length of param array :)